# グローバル関数から無名（匿名）関数に入りたい

Tags: javascript

Google API の JavaScriptクライアントライブラリを使っているのですが、グローバル関数から無名関数の処理の中に入る（？）よい方法が思い浮かばず悩んでいます。

</body>の前に、(1)自分のJavaScript読み込み (2)Google API読み込み を記載しています。

```
    :
<script src="MY.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=GoogleApiLoad"></script>
</body>
```

MY.js では、グローバルな名前をできるだけ作らないよう無名関数の中で、Google API とは関係なく先にできる処理を行ってます。

```
!function(){
    // 先にできることいろいろ
}();
```

そして、Google API のロード完了後に、この無名関数の中で処理を続行したいのですが、どんなコードにすればよいのかわかりません。

Google API の使い方は、ロード完了したタイミングでコールバック関数を実行する方式(client.js?onload=XXX)が公式的なようなので、それに従っています。
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

このコールバック関数(上の例ではGoogleApiLoad)は、グローバルな名前でないといけないと思いますが、そうすると、

```
!function(){
    // 先にできることいろいろ
    // Google APIロード完了後はAPIを使っていろいろ
}();

function GoogleApiLoad(){
    // Google APIロード完了
}
```

・基本は無名関数で自分のJavaScriptコードを実行している中で、
・Google API がロード完了したら、その無名関数の中でAPIを使って処理を続行する

というやり方をしたい時に、どうすればよいのか・・よい方法が思い浮かびません。。

こういう時は、どうするのがよいのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window` に代入すればグローバル変数になります。この場合 [`this` は `window` を指す](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Global_context) ので `this` に代入するのでも構いません。

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      !function(){
        var anonymousFunc = function() {
           alert('anonymous!');
        };
        // this.GoogleApiLoad でもよい
        window.GoogleApiLoad = function() {
          anonymousFunc();
        }
      }();
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=GoogleApiLoad></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: なるほど！！！動きました！！！
こういう時にwindowを使うのですね・・！
ありがとうございました！！！m(_ _)m

Answer (score 2):

グローバル変数を定義する場合はこうですが…

```js
var GoogleApiLoad;
function() {
    // このスクリプト読み込み時のコード

    GoogleApiLoad = function() {
        // モジュールロード後のコード
    }
}();
```

ソースを眺めるとコールバックのデフォルトが `gapi_onload` なので、こうすればいけそう。

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
// このブロックは　My.js の中だと仮定して
!function() {
    // このスクリプト読み込み時のコード
    window.alert("Hello from function()!");
    
    // 読み込み時は定義するだけ
    window["gapi_onload"] = function() {
        // モジュールロード後のコード
        window.alert("Hello from function() again!");
    }
}();
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！ どちらの方法でも動きました！！！ なるほどonload=XXXを書かなくても gapi_onload で動くのですね・・！